# const_missing error when changing I18n backedn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upgrade the I18n backend of my application to use the database instead of the yml files for internationalization.  I'm following the steps found for the I18n-active_record gem found here: https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record.

Unfortunately, the aws-s3 gem seems to be conflicting somehow as I can't even start my server or console once I create the locale.rb initializer.  Here is a summary of the steps I'm following:

```
gem "i18n-active_record", "~> 0.0.2"
create new file config/initializers/locale.rb
inside locale.rb
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Database.new
restart localhost server to load initializer
```

Error Message

/Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@app/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant I18n::Backend::Database (NameError)
...(Several more lines)

Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the readme in github says so, I don't think the Database constant is actually defined by the gem. Try

```
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.new
```

Comment: At https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record it's suggested how to mention the gem within Gemfile. Can you try that?

Comment: When I used that it doesn't even install the bundle.  Some kind of git clone error.  I uncommented aws-s3 to see if that solved the issue, but the error still persisted.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Using the correct git parameter along with the ActiveRecord.new in your answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Great question and great discussion.  The answer is contained in a combination of the comments up above, but for those of you who are upgrading to a Rails 3 application, this is a summary of the steps I had to take.

Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'i18n-active_record', :require => 'i18n/active_record'
```

Add this to a new config file config/initializers/locale.rb

```
require 'i18n/backend/active_record'
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.new
```

Take out any code in application.rb that was previously initializing the record store.  This clears the missing content errors.  Full instructions are on the Github repo for this backend module which was removed from the core I18n: https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record

Comment: I'll also note that I ended up using the globalize 3 gem instead of i18n/active_record.  Definitely check it out and see if it is a fit for you.